# how can i open jsp/servlet page from remote pc?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

first of all i will thank to who will help me out this..

my actually question is that , there is two pc in LAN in my house. and i make LAN connection between them, so pc1 is call as server because it has tomcat server and whole project which are made into jsp/servlet. then , how can i open pc1(server) 's jsp page from pc2(another) pc.

thank you
mihir gandhrokiya

Answer (score 4):

```
 http://{server.ip.here}:8080/app/some.jsp
```

Make sure you don't have a firewall blocking the connection.

Comment: http(s) if it's a secured location. ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
SERVERIP:SERVERPORT/appcontext/jsppage.jsp
```

for example

```
192.1.200.102:8080/myApp/music.jsp
```

**Note**: you don't need to mention port for `http` if server is serving on port `80`,for `https` its `443`

[1]: http:// 209.85.231.104

Comment: life.java: Actually, I was about to downvote you (kiddin) because of your `sip:server` nonsense, but then I saw your reasonable answer, after I refreshed the page :). So, I guess someone is still unaware of your edit.

Comment: @Adeel Ansari  previous one was just not formatted btw. it wasn't sip:server it was unformatted so `server'sip`

Comment: life.java: No worries, I will counter that. :)

Comment: @Adeel Ansari Thanks anyways :).. *@downvoter* please clear your misunderstanding

Answer (score -1):

Connect CROSS-CABLE(LAN) between PC1(Server) and PC2(Client) configure IP like

### PC1

IP:192.168.0.1
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0

### for PC2

IP:192.168.0.2
subnet mask:255.255.255.0

if your project URL like (http://192.168.0.1:8080/project/index.jsp) on your server side (PC1).
you can browse the page from client side (PC2) using (http://192.168.0.1:8080/project/index.jsp)